# homepage property in package.json

Tags: reactjs

In my package.json I declared a property  "homepage": "https://test/sites/test". But the url changes depending on the environment. Is there a way to make it fluid depending on git branch you are working on? Because in our git we got 2 branches master and uat. master is for our production which uses the production url while uat uses uat url. Any suggestion how to change them?

Comment: Sounds like a job for dotenv

Comment: I'm thinking you are using package.json for something it really isn't designed for. homepage should be your prod homepage. Different staging environments can be defined with one of the various configuration schemes out there. node-config, env vars, dotenv, etc.

Comment: Hmm so I should remove it from package.json and move it somewhere? But how it will know what branch I am using? TIA

Comment: @Derek Polland I have a question though. If we are going to define our url in an untracked environment file(.env), then switchin branch wont affect the target url and youll end up with 1 url no matter what branch you use.